# MPEG-4 file behavior

Tags: iphone

In iphone i have a mpeg-4 video file, which when played & when i click in the middle or any portion of the video, its goes back & starts from beginning rather continuing from the place where i clicked.

Whereas the same file plays when the same behavior is extorted(ie. play, click in the middle of the video) works fine in quicktime player/safari.

Do someone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: This isn't really about programming *or* about MPEG-4 files. It's about the programs you're using to play MPEG-4 files.

Answer (score 0):

The video proabably only has one keyframe at the beginning of the clip.

That means to recreate the image in the middle of the video, the player needs to go back to the first frame and apply the rules from every spanning frame. A good video player on powerful hardware would be able to calculate what the 20,000th frame on the fly essentially by playing the entire video to that point. However, that is quite a lot of calculation, so a less powerful video player (like one on a phone), would not be able to make all of the necessary calculations in a timely manner much faster than real time, so it might simply go back to the beginning.

One solution would be to put key-frames more frequently. That way you have a higher seek precision. Every 1-2 seconds is pretty standard and used by DirectTV (That is why it can sometimes take a second to change the station. Th box can't render the image until it receives a keyframe.)

---

A little explanation of keyframes...

If you don't know what a keyframe is, you need to understand a little about video compression. An uncompressed video would store the complete image for each frame. So, 30 frames would be the equivalent of jpgs (or other image format).

One of the larges gains in compression comes when, instead of storing the complete image in each frame, you only store the information that was different. For example, if you have a static scene and a ball flies through it, you only have to describe the path of the ball.

There are many rules for this calculation. Some of the rules are philosophically similar to the manner in which traditional animators layered cels above a static background. Other rules more resemble the way [William Kentridge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmvK7A84dlk) modifies the previous frame in his charcoal animation by panning, erasing, or drawing over.

---

[Here is a good explanation of the mpeg-4 standard](http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/mpeg-4.htm)